# Can an object have more than one literal value for a data property in OWL?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I designed an ontology model for a Smart House. A sensor attached to each object. In my ontology, I have a class `Sensor`. Each object in this class has an Id-number. For example, `Cabinet` is an individual of `Sensor`. I have several `Cabinet` with different Id-number in the Kitchen such as `Cabinet hasID# 42`, `Cabinet hasID# 52`. I am using protege, I define `hasID` as a data property and `locatedIn` as an object property. I want to know is it possible to have:

```
Cabinet locatedIn Kitchen
Cabinet hasID 42
Cabinet hasID 52
```

or should I change the `hasID` to an object property and define a class `IdNumber`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. First of all: do you want two different properties (`hadID` and `hasID`) or two different values for the same property? Secondly: what difficulty are you experiencing with adding this property in Protege? You obviously managed to add several properties already...

Comment: Having two value for a data property. something like this ex "hasID 42, 52"

Comment: It's still not clear what your problem is. You're giving conflicting information - your comment above suggests two values for a property on the same object, but in your comment in the answer you talk about two different objects (two doors). Be specific in what you _actually_ mean, and [edit] your question. Show an example, and/or what you've tried. And please have a look at [ask], which gives you good tips on how to ask a good question here on StackOverflow. Following these tips will improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: I don't know how to apologize. This is my first time, I ask a question on Stackoverflow. I edit my question, so I hope that it is not vague anymore. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are approaching this the wrong way, I think. You do not have one Cabinet with several IDs, you have *several* *different* cabinets. In other words, you have two individuals, each of **type** `Cabinet`. One has id 42, the other has id 52.

In (pseudo) RDF triples:

```
:cabinet42 a :Cabinet ;
           :locatedIn :kitchen ;
           :hasID 42 .

:cabinet52 a :Cabinet ;
           :locatedIn :kitchen ;
           :hasID 52 .
```

So in Protege, you need to create two separate individuals, one for each cabinet, and then give each individual its own ID property.

As an aside, as you can see in the above RDF, it may not even be necessary to give them `:hasID` properties at all: they each already have their own unique identifier (namely their URIs: `:cabinet42` and `:cabinet52`).